# List and download videos from youtube audio library in python

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hello I am finding a way to download the audio from youtube audio library via api or other means without using the selenium method (it's too slow to work with).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [YouTube Audio Library](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/UC/music) then YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide any endpoint to download these audio files. You can't make the process faster except by going down to a lower level by using curl and downloading these audio in a multithread way.